# How to customized woo commerce Customer Created webhooks

Tags: woocommerce, webhooks, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using woo commerce "Customer Created" webhook  which will post data to external URL as well as a new user created in woo commerce, I am receiving all data properly except the user's password.
Can any one guide me in which file I need to make change so this hook will post user's password as well
Note- In woo commerce setting Auto create username& password is disabled so user have to manually fill these fields

Following data woo commerce sending to my url

```
{"id":4,"date_created":"2017-06-08T06:12:47","date_created_gmt":"2017-06-08T06:12:47","date_modified":"2017-06-08T06:12:47","date_modified_gmt":"2017-06-08T06:12:47","email":"citrpro@hotmail.com","first_name":"Kirti","last_name":"Jensen","role":"customer","username":"citationbuilderpro@hotmail.com","billing":{"first_name":"Kirti","last_name":"Jensen","company":"SEALOOM TX","address_1":"13359 North Highway 183 Suite 406-589","address_2":"","city":"Austin","state":"AK","postcode":"78750","country":"US","email":"citrpro@hotmail.com","phone":"5125151300"},"shipping":{"first_name":"","last_name":"","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":""},"is_paying_customer":false,"orders_count":1,"total_spent":"0.00","avatar_url":"http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/b46fd47ff44e507a64dd9ede8673c0e6?s=96","meta_data":[{"id":126,"key":"_yoast_wpseo_profile_updated","value":"1496902367"},{"id":140,"key":"shipping_method","value":""}]}
```

Thanks